# Is there a way in Visual C++ using WinAPI to get the file-path to the executable file of an open window?

Tags: visual-c++

Forgive me if this has been asked already, although I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem.

I currently have a console project that is able to enumerate desktop windows and print out to the console their title and handle. I'm trying to also get the program to print out each window's path, that is, the path to the executable file that is responsible for that window's existence.

The output I am expecting in my console, per window, is as follows:

```
          Title (caption) of window
Handle:   HWND of window
Path:     C:\Path to\window\process.exe
```

For example, if there are windows open that are notepad and firefox, then I would like the console to read:

```
          Untitled - Notepad
Handle:   000000000006118C
Path:     C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe

          Mozilla Firefox
Handle:   00000000001C02E8
Path:     C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

However, the state of my program right now has the console outputting:

```
          Untitled - Notepad
Handle:   000000000006118C
Path:     C:\Users\[My Name]\source\repos\[Program Name]\x64\Debug\[Program].exe

          Mozilla Firefox
Handle:   00000000001C02E8
Path:     C:\Users\[My Name]\source\repos\[Program Name]\x64\Debug\[Program].exe
```

Notice how the path is returning only the path of the project program, rather than the path of the window's .exe file.

The function in my code that is supposed to be retrieving the path of the program window is:

```
std::string GetWindowExe(HWND hWnd)
{
    wchar_t* pFileName = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, pFileName, MAX_PATH);
    std::wstring wsExe(pFileName);
    std::string sExe(wsExe.begin(), wsExe.end());
    delete[] pFileName;
    return sExe;
}
```

If you are going to play with this function, make sure to include <Windows.h>

I was under the impression that I should use GetModuleFileName <Windows.h> just because that was what my initial research for the task had led me to, however I'm starting to doubt that I'm using the correct function, or perhaps I am using it incorrectly. (I also wonder if I'm using the right variable type (wchar_t*) to handle the LPWSTR parameter)

I have also read that I might be able to use GetModuleFileNameEx <Psapi.h> but I haven't been able to get it to work yet, and I am not confident that it will even work.I think I may need the PID to do this, but I'm not sure where to go. Recent searches have been fruitless for me.

Does anybody know what I should do to accomplish this task? Any help would be much appreciated!

TLDR: I'm trying to create a function that will return a string corresponding to the path to an executable file of a window, the handle of which is known and passed to this function

```
std::string PathFunction(HWND hWindowHandle)
{
    // Some code that takes the window's handle and returns the path to the .exe file
    std::string sPath = SomeFunc(HWND hWindowHandle, SOMETYPE Params)
    return sPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago I tried to accomplish more or less exactly the same what you try now.
This is the codepiece which finally translates the given HWND into the file path of the issuing executable. Be aware though that this just works well if your window enumerator tool runs with elevated privileges.

```
wchar_t awcModule[_MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwProcessId;

if( GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &dwProcessId ) )
{
    if( HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, dwProcessId ) )
    {
        if( !GetModuleFileNameEx( hProcess, 0, awcModule, _MAX_PATH ) )
        {
            DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();

            if( dwErr != ERROR_AUTODATASEG_EXCEEDS_64k )  // heuristic finding that this may happen but is no issue
            {
                // errorhandling GetModuleFileNameEx() failure
            }
        }

        CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }
    else
    {
        // errorhandling OpenProcess() failure
    }
}
else
{
    // errorhandling GetWindowThreadProcessId() failure
}

// if no error-condition occured awcModule should have the path now
```

Comment: I have imported your code into a function, and I'm running into a little issue which was why I couldn't get my attempts of using GetModuleFileNameEx to work. Even though I've imported <Psapi.h>, it gives me an error on GetModuleFileNameEx where the error reads "identifier 'K32GetModuleFileNameExW' is undefined". 

It is as if Psapi.h doesn't actually have the function in it. I'm using Visual Studio 22.
Would you happen to know how to go about this?

Comment: I'm using VS2022 as well and haven't experienced such issue.
A short research tells that several psapi-functions have moved from psapi.dll to kernel.dll starting with Win7. The new kernel-versions are prefixed K32... The old non-K32 entry-points for these functions are still available in psapi.dll with and past Win7, but they're just wrappers for the new K32... kernel-versions. The standard headers should handle this situation transparently based on the target OS-versions of your project. Maybe your project has an inconsistency regarding the defines and switches for the target OS-versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured it out. It was a minor issue on my part where I was including <Windows.h> after <Psapi.h> rather than before it. I am prone to these minor issues, but I should have informed you as soon as I figured it out. Apologies, but thanks for your suggestions! My original problem has been fixed using your code.